# Is there a way to make WebStorm fix all imports when I move a file in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, import, webstorm

Every time I move a file in my TypeScript project all the imports of that file break.

Can I configure WebStorm so that it fixes them automatically when I move a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webstorm updates all references to the moved file if you check "Search for references" option.

[image]